# Simulate ATM login function

Tags: python, authentication

I'm a fresh python learner, I just want to write a function about ATM login.
I'm stuck at password retry part, so could anyone help me out.

About this function info:
1. Account is logged at a file at 'userdb.txt'

account  password total left status

1234567 111111 1500 1500 1

2345678 222222 1500 1500 1

3456789 333333 1500 1500 1

4567890 444444 1500 1500 1

5678901 555555 1500 1500 1

2. user could login ATM with correct account, password and status is '1'.
3. if user login with incorrect password over 3 times, the user is locked, and the status is set to '0'.
4. but when I get to password retry part, i have no sense about password retry part, how to return the value or something about password retry, and at last I'm confused when call this function to test password retry.

   ```
               pass_loop += 1
               #print 'The password is not correct, please enter again!' # I'm confused here, how to judge password retry, if user input incorrect password.
               return 'Retry'
               continue
   ```

---

```
import os

import sys

import fileinput



def account_Login(userName, userPass):

    account_dic = {} # define a null dictionary
    with open("D:\userdb.txt") as f: #load account info to dic.
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.strip( ).split( )
            account_dic[line[0]] = line[1:]

    while True:
        is_find = 0
        if account_dic.has_key(userName) == True: # if the account is in account dic.
            is_find = 1       # if account is valid, then go to password and status check.
        else:
            return 'Account Is Not Existed, Please Retry'
            continue
        if is_find == 1:
            is_lock = 0
            is_login = 0
            pass_loop = 0
            while pass_loop < 3:
                if userPass == account_dic[userName][0] and account_dic[userName][3] == '1': # if password correct and status is '1', login ok.
                    is_login = 1
                    break
                elif userPass == account_dic[userName][0] and account_dic[userName][3] == '0': # if password correct and status is '0', user locked.
                    is_lock = 1
                    break
                else:
                    pass_loop += 1
                    #print 'The password is not correct, please enter again!' # I'm confused here, how to judge password retry, if user input incorrect password.
                    return 'Retry'
                    continue

            if pass_loop == 3:
                for line1 in fileinput.input("D:\userdb.txt", inplace=1, backup='.bak'):
                    line1 = line1.replace(userName + ' ' + ' '.join(account_dic[userName][0:3]) + ' ' + '1', userName + ' ' + ' '.join(account_dic[userName][0:3]) + ' ' + '0').strip('\n')
                    print line1      
                return 'Account Is Locked, Please Contact Support Stuff'
                break
            if is_login == 1:
                return 'Login Successfully'
                break
            if is_lock == 1:
                return 'Account Is Locked, Please Contact Support Stuff'
                break



while True:


    userName1 = raw_input('please enter your account: ')
    userPass1 = raw_input('please enter your password: ')
    print account_Login(userName1, userPass1)
    if account_Login(userName1, userPass1) == 'Account Is Locked, Please Contact Support Stuff':
        break
    elif account_Login(userName1, userPass1) == 'Login Successfully':
        break
    elif account_Login(userName1, userPass1) == 'Account Is Not Existed, Please Retry':
        continue
    else:
        ########### how to call password retry part.
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import namedtuple
#describe a record
record = namedtuple("record","account password total left active")
#create a list of records
with open("userdb.txt") as f:
    accounts = map(record._make,map(str.split,f))
#convert it to a dict so it is easy to access by account number
user_db = dict((acct.account,acct) for acct in accounts)

#handle the login
def login(user,password):
    user_account = user_db.get(user,None)
    if user_account is None: 
        return #failed login user does not exist
    if user_account.password != password:
        return #failed password does not match
    if user_account.active == "1":
        return user_db[user]

#get the user within N retries or fail
def get_user(retries=3):
    for i in range(retries): #retry N times
        selected_user = login(raw_input("Enter Account #:"),raw_input("Enter Pin:"))
        if not selected_user:
            print "Invalid Login Retry!!!"
            continue
        return selected_user

if __name__ == "__main__":
    user = get_user(5)
    if not user:
        print "Sorry Too Many Retries... try again later."
    else:
        print "Logged In As:",user
```